# Where can I find the lexicon machine for "Discerning the Transmundane"?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm on the quest *Discerning the Transmundane*, but I can't find the room with the lexicon machine.

In Blackreach, I've found the Debate Hall, Silent Ruin, Halls of Rumination, and War Quarters, but haven't found it yet. I've been running around this place for over an hour now!

Where, in relation to the giant golden globe, can I find the machine?

Comment: Just to double check, have you enabled the quest in your journal? Once you're in black reach, the quest marker is a pretty good guide on how to get to the Tower of Mzulft elevator where the transcription machine is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The giant golden globe roughly in the centre of Blackreach is not the lexicon machine, but it provides a useful point of reference to find it. While standing below the giant golden globe, walk directly south. As you pass through the southern gate of the wall, you will be on top of a set of stairs. Slightly to your right is a tall tower that connects to the ceiling. This is the Tower of Mzark. To reach it, you will cross a bridge over rapids which flow to the edge of a waterfall. When you reach the tower, take the elevator to the tower's interior, solve the puzzle, and you will be able to transcribe the Elder Scroll into the lexicon and then retrieve the Elder Scroll from the machine.

Answer (score 2):

The Tower of Mzark is in the southwest of Blackreach near the Farm Overseer's House. You'll use the elevator to get to the lexicon machine.

Answer (score 1):

The giant golden globe IS the lexicon machine.

Standing on the globe, there are two staircases that wrap around and up, leading to a platform above the globe.  One side of that device will accept the horadric cube... errr.. lexicon.

(You can look up details if you can't figure out how to solve this puzzle.  It was non obvious to me at first.)

Comment: I believe the "Golden Globe" they were referring to was the giant lamp containing the trigger for the secret dragon fight. The one that hangs over the structure between Sinderion's hut and the Tower of Mzulft elevator

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone else who comes across this thread, there are TWO giant globes discussed here. The first is more like a large lantern that's visible within the Blackreach main area. You walk south from that globe to find the Tower of Mzark, which is where the second, and much larger, globe is found. That second globe is the tool used for transcribing the lexicon.